# Scrapy - nested link extraction using selectors

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I have the following problem: There is a website which is the start point for the crawler (the "start URL")

```
https://www.example.com
```

on that page, there is a list of links which I can get that way using selectors:

```
response.css('div[id=aaaaa][class=bbbbb] a::attr(href)').getall()
```

in **each of the pages** returned by the above command, there is a list of links I can get that way using selectors:

```
response.css('td[class=ccccc] a::attr(href)').getall()
```

and these are the "end pages" I actually want to scrape. The issue is that I don't think I can realistically do it using rules, because the links don't really have one rule they follow like "Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('HEREARETHETHINGSYOUWANTLOL.php', ))", and the links I want are "nested", so to speak

so basically I have two questions:

1. How to make scrapy scrape all of the "end links"
2. The "end links" are **not** in the "https://www.example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc" format, they are in the "aaa/bbb/ccc" format. Can that be a problem?

Comment: Have a look at  the other parameters of LinkExtractor. Those include `restrict_css`. As for **2**, I don’t think relative links are an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity: I managed to figure it out. That is how you do this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.css('div[id=aaaaa][class=bbbbb] a'):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.example.com"+sel.css('a::attr(href)').get(), callback=self.parse_2)

def parse_2(self, response):
    for sel in response.css('td[class=ccccc] a'):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.example.com" + sel.css('a::attr(href)').get(), callback=self.parse_3)

def parse_3(self, response):
    for stf in response.css('yourelement'):
        yield {
            'somethingyouactuallywanttoscrape': "etc"
        }
```